# How to generate the output label of clusters from k means clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

My input feature set is in form of a csv file. I have used 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html
 to select number of  clusters on my unlabeled data and  am getting a highest score for cluster size =3 
Therefore my cluster =3.  Is there a way I can generate the output labels for each of the input rows  for kmeans clustering algorithm?

Basically I want print out all input  features and  results (cluster labels) of the kmeans algorithm 
Ie I want print out all input features and cluster labels assigned to each row of input csv file.

Code in python

```
import pandas
from pandas import read_csv
names = ["Variable1”, "Variable2”, "Variable3”, "Variable4”, "Variable5”, "Variable6”, "Variable7”, "Variable8”, "Variable9”, "Variable10”, "Variable11”, "Variable12”, "InputClass”]
filename = 'C:/Users/svx/d_features.csv'
dataframe = read_csv(filename, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,2:11]
range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
    # Create a subplot with 1 row and 2 columns
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    fig.set_size_inches(18, 7)

    # The 1st subplot is the silhouette plot
    # The silhouette coefficient can range from -1, 1 but in this example all
    # lie within [-0.1, 1]
    ax1.set_xlim([-0.1, 1])
    # The (n_clusters+1)*10 is for inserting blank space between silhouette
    # plots of individual clusters, to demarcate them clearly.
    ax1.set_ylim([0, len(X) + (n_clusters + 1) * 10])

    # Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
    # seed of 10 for reproducibility.
    clusterer = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, random_state=10)
    cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X)

    # The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
    # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
    # clusters
    silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
    print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
          "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

    # Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
    sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, cluster_labels)

    y_lower = 10
    for i in range(n_clusters):
        # Aggregate the silhouette scores for samples belonging to
        # cluster i, and sort them
        ith_cluster_silhouette_values = \
            sample_silhouette_values[cluster_labels == i]

        ith_cluster_silhouette_values.sort()

        size_cluster_i = ith_cluster_silhouette_values.shape[0]
        y_upper = y_lower + size_cluster_i

        color = cm.spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)
        ax1.fill_betweenx(np.arange(y_lower, y_upper),
                          0, ith_cluster_silhouette_values,
                          facecolor=color, edgecolor=color, alpha=0.7)

        # Label the silhouette plots with their cluster numbers at the middle
        ax1.text(-0.05, y_lower + 0.5 * size_cluster_i, str(i))

        # Compute the new y_lower for next plot
        y_lower = y_upper + 10  # 10 for the 0 samples

    ax1.set_title("The silhouette plot for the various clusters.")
    ax1.set_xlabel("The silhouette coefficient values")
    ax1.set_ylabel("Cluster label")

    # The vertical line for average silhouette score of all the values
    ax1.axvline(x=silhouette_avg, color="red", linestyle="--")

    ax1.set_yticks([])  # Clear the yaxis labels / ticks
    ax1.set_xticks([-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])

    # 2nd Plot showing the actual clusters formed
    colors = cm.spectral(cluster_labels.astype(float) / n_clusters)
    ax2.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='.', s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7,
                c=colors)

    # Labeling the clusters
    centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_
    # Draw white circles at cluster centers
    ax2.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1],
                marker='o', c="white", alpha=1, s=200)

    for i, c in enumerate(centers):
        ax2.scatter(c[0], c[1], marker='$%d$' % i, alpha=1, s=50)

    ax2.set_title("The visualization of the clustered data.")
    ax2.set_xlabel("Feature space for the 1st feature")
    ax2.set_ylabel("Feature space for the 2nd feature")

    plt.suptitle(("Silhouette analysis for KMeans clustering on sample data "
                  "with n_clusters = %d" % n_clusters),
                 fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Uhm, what about `cluster_labels`?

Comment: cluster_labels gives an array  of  6 values . The result is  not based on best  distance: i did np.unique(cluster_labels) which gave me array [0,1,2,3,4,5].  this means it printed out the result for 6 clusters using range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] . In my case, using the above code I found that my best cluster size =3 and I want to print cluster labels when my cluster size =3  .

Comment: Keep a copy of the best.